# Convert Hex value to Base64 using Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, base64, hex

I have this value:

```
263e5df7a93ec5f5ea6ac215ed957c30
```

When I fill this in on: https://8gwifi.org/base64Hex.jsp (Hex to Base64)
It gives me back:

```
Jj5d96k+xfXqasIV7ZV8MA==
```

This is the expected value. However, when I try this in Kotlin,

```
val encodedHexB64 = Base64.encodeToString("263e5df7a93ec5f5ea6ac215ed957c30".toByteArray(UTF_8), Base64.NO_WRAP)
```

It gives me back:

```
MjYzZTVkZjdhOTNlYzVmNWVhNmFjMjE1ZWQ5NTdjMzA=
```

How to get the correct value in Kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the input string represents 16 bytes, where each byte is coded with two hex digit chars of that string.

On the contrary `toByteArray(UTF_8)` encodes the string in UTF-8 encoding turning each char into one or more bytes. When you convert these bytes to base64, first you get the longer result and second — these are completely different bytes.

I suppose the correct way to convert the input hex string into byte array would be:

```
    val input = "263e5df7a93ec5f5ea6ac215ed957c30"
    val bytes = input.chunked(2).map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }.toByteArray()
```

Then you encode these `bytes` to base64 as usual.

Answer (score 3):

To complete the previous:

```
val input = "263e5df7a93ec5f5ea6ac215ed957c30"
val bytes = input.chunked(2).map { it.toInt(16).toByte() }.toByteArray()
val encodeBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT)
```

Now you have: Jj5d96k+xfXqasIV7ZV8MA==